# (Unofficial) StackExchange WWDC Meet Up — 7th June, 2011

Tags: discussion, wwdc

*Cross posted from [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92181/89035)*

**When:** Tuesday, 7th June 2011
**Location:** Eddie Rickenbacker's ([Google Maps Dirsections](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=moscone%20west&daddr=133%202nd%20St,%20San%20Francisco,%20CA%2094105&hl=en&geocode=FV6GQAIdE0e0-CEn9gyL1OYTtQ;FRyYQAId_Va0-CmPwA0sfYCFgDFciIsMAGT-TQ&mra=ltm&dirflg=w&sll=37.78475,-122.402835&sspn=0.006868,0.015686&ie=UTF8&ll=37.785292,-122.400613&spn=0.006868,0.015686&z=17)) ([yelp](http://www.yelp.com/biz/eddie-rickenbackers-san-francisco))

### [Sign Up Here](http://plancast.com/p/5ifv)

> 5000+ international Developers will be
> in San Francisco between 5th June and
> 11th. It seems like an ideal
> opportunity to have an unofficial
> StackExchange [objective-c](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) / [ios](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) / [cocoa](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cocoa) / [iphone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone)
> meet-up.

*NB: This is totally unofficial, please don't expect t-shirts and unicorn bucks*

Comment: I don't see an edit link below this post, and that "Dirsections" typo above is mocking me...

Comment: Can we do this again this year?